# How to review past games

Tags: analysis, software

1. Does a software that analyzes your past games and gives you tips exist?
2. If there exist, is there a way to implement it, so we can play against "ourselves"
3. If not, how do you review and analyze usually? It seems to me that many games are too specific, to have enough value to remember it, especially if one plays more as a hobby

Comment: The best i could find is chess hero, seems quite useful, in a sense it satisfy 1 and 2. Any similar software?